# Detect change to element id=ASIN when Ajax is making changes

Tags: javascript

This question is more of a general coding practice question. I am writing an extension for Google Chrome that gathers the ASIN number from Amazon.com when viewing an item page.

Design requirements:

1. When viewing a page that contains an element with id=ASIN, capture the ASIN. (E.g. B004FYJFNA from [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004FYJFNA/?tag=justinreinhart-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004FYJFNA) )
2. When user changes platforms (e.g. from Playstation 3 to Xbox 360), detect that a change has occurred and capture the new ASIN value.

I have a "content script", injection.js, that is injected on every amazon page and can successfully perform requirement #1.

The issue I have is with #2. I am not able to *efficiently* detect a change to the ASIN value. Either the code doesn't fire OR I pick an element that fires ~100 times. I am at a loss how to do this efficiently.

Failure examples:

```
// (A) This fires ~100 times when user changes platforms,
// and also fires during mouseover events.
// Unacceptable but it does work.
$("#handleBuy").bind('DOMNodeRemoved', OnProductChange);

// (B) This doesn't fire at all. I have a few guesses why but no certainties.  
$("#ASIN").on('change', OnProductChange);
```

Blathering:
Switching product platforms when the user clicks seems to tear the Amazon page apart and it destroys any event binding that I attempt. (I believe the element is removed and reinserted--not just changed.) I do not know javascript well enough to skillfully take these massive DOM changes into account.

Your help and knowledge is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `$(document).on('change', '#ASIN', onProductChange);`? The event will not fire if the element is dynamically added to the page using on, unless you specify a DOM node higher than it in the tree.

Comment: Good info. I learned something. However, this also does not fire when the user switches platforms. I'm not sure how to proceed to understand why it fails.

Comment: I should also note I would be interested in being directed to any tools that would let me debug this and determine why it is failing. My background is C# and PHP, not javascript. So something may be obvious here but I'm just not seeing it nor do I know how to troubleshoot it. However, I feel this is trickier than it looks. I would love someone else to attempt it.